# Ordering data in a Flask Appbuilder view

Tags: python, flask

I am using Flask Appbuilder 1.5.0 and have the following Model

```
class RegistrationTest(Model, ModelEnhancer):
    __tablename__ = "Registration"
    RegistrationID = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    CarNo = Column(String(10), nullable=False)
    FirstName = Column(String(30))
    LastName = Column(String(30))
    CarClassID = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('CarClass.CarClassID'), nullable=False)
    CarClass = relationship("CarClass")
```

And the following View

```
class RegistrationTestView(ModelView ):
    datamodel = SQLAInterface(RegistrationTest)
    name = "RegistrationTestView"
    page_size=1000
    label_columns = {'CarNo':'Car #', 'FirstName':'First Name','LastName':'Last Name'}
    list_columns = ['CarNo','FirstName','LastName']
    edit_columns = ['FirstName','LastName']
    show_columns = edit_columns
    add_columns = edit_columns
    order_columns = ['FirstName']
```

No matter what value(s) I put in the order_columns list the data is always ordered by CarNo, which is the primary key. Any suggestions on what I need to do to order the output by another column?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add [`base_order`](https://flask-appbuilder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#flask_appbuilder.baseviews.BaseModelView.base_order) to your code.

Customizing `Flask-appbuilder` requires you to override the [`BaseModelView`](https://flask-appbuilder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#basemodelview) using the [API Reference](https://flask-appbuilder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html):

> base_order = None
>
> Use this property to set default ordering for lists
>   (‘col_name’,’asc|desc’):

```
class MyView(ModelView):
     datamodel = SQLAInterface(MyTable)
     base_order = ('my_column_name','asc')
```

On the other hand `order_columns` is an override which specifies whether you permit your user to re-order the columns asc¦desc.