# How to define display order of edit view in Flask appbuilder?

Tags: flask-appbuilder

According to document of flask appbuilder, the display order of Model detail view can be defined as following:

```
class DeviceView(ModelView):        
    datamodel = SQLAInterface(Device)
    related_views = [ApplicationView, EventView]

    label_columns = {'snr':'SNR', 'api_dev_id':'Device ID', 'api_dev_key':'Device Key','owner_id':'Owner'}
    list_columns = ['name','snr','addr','owner']

    show_fieldsets = [
        ('Summary',
            {'fields':['name','snr','owner']}
        ),
        ('Device Info',
            {'fields':    ['addr','latitude','longitude','status','api_id','api_key','api_dev_id','api_dev_key'],'expanded':True}
        ),
    ]
```

And it works for detail view. But I can not find the definition for edit view. Here is my snapshot for Device edit page. The order seems random.

Have I missed any part inside the document?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer from another question:
[Ordering data in a Flask Appbuilder view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44122420/ordering-data-in-a-flask-appbuilder-view)

```
class RegistrationTestView(ModelView ):
    datamodel = SQLAInterface(RegistrationTest)
    name = "RegistrationTestView"
    page_size=1000
    label_columns = {'CarNo':'Car #', 'FirstName':'First Name','LastName':'Last Name'}
    list_columns = ['CarNo','FirstName','LastName']
    edit_columns = ['FirstName','LastName']
    show_columns = edit_columns
    add_columns = edit_columns
    order_columns = ['FirstName']
```

Display in edit/list/show are ordered seperately.

Comment: I'm getting  `TypeError: must be real number, not str`, have you come across this too ?